# What are the inner workings of this lambda expression inside the filter function?

Tags: haskell, filter, functional-programming, distance, lambda-calculus

I have functions defined as follows:

```
distance3 :: String -> String -> Float
distance3 x y = fromIntegral $ abs $ length x - length y

distanceFilter :: (String -> String -> Float) -> Float -> String
  -> [String] -> [String]
distanceFilter f d s ss = filter (\x -> f s x <= d) ss
```

The distanceFilter returns all the strings in ss that are at most d distance away from s.

It works as it is supposed to, but I have trouble understanding the inner workings of

```
filter (\x -> f s x <=d) ss
```

Obviously the \x -> takes a string from the list ss and applies it to the function f as the second parameter, but how does it do that? How does it know how to take the element? How does that lambda expression work?

Comment: The short answer is that the function created by the lambda expression closes over the values of `f`, `d`, and `s`. You basically seem to be asking "how are closures implemented?"

Comment: What do you mean by "How does it know how to take the element?" How does *what* know? Take the element of what? Being more precise in your question and thinking will help you understand more clearly what is going on here. Always take a second look at words like "it" to make sure you know what "it" you are referring to. And when you are asking the question publicly, replace "it" with something more specific and concrete.

Answer (score 1):

```
distanceFilter f d s ss = filter (\x -> f s x <= d) ss
```

There are two separate aspects to your question:

1. The lambda "closes" over the values from the outer scope. In this case, `f`, `s` and `d` in `(\x -> f s x <= d)` refer to the parameters of the function and get their values from the arguments that are passed in. This is called a "closure". You can do some more research on your own to understand more deeply.
2. `filter` determines what values are passed as `x` to the lambda. By definition, `filter f xs` applies the function `f` to each element of the list `xs`. So `x` in your lambda will be each element of `ss` in turn. Implementing your own version of `filter` is a great exercise to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

`\x -> f s x <= d` constructs a function that takes a string and returns a `Bool`, it thus has type `String -> Bool`. It is equivalent to defining a function `go` like:

```
go :: String -> Bool
go x = f s x <= d
```

and thus calling this function `go` as filter predicate.

`filter` will call the predicate on all items. It is [implemented as <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#filter):

> ```
> filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
> filter _pred []    = []
> filter pred (x:xs)
>   | pred x         = x : filter pred xs
>   | otherwise      = filter pred xs
> ```

For an empty list it thus returns an empty list, and for a non-empty list, it calls `pred` with `x` as parameter, and if the predicate returns `True`, it yields `x`. In both cases it recurses on the rest of the list.

So the filter calls the predicate with the elements of the list, and since the lambda expression thus is a function that takes such parameter as input, it can be used to determine whether it should yield an element `x` or not.